# Borel set, excercise

Tags: real-analysis

I need help with this excercise:

> Prove that every open set is a Borel set by showing that for each open
>   set, $O$, $\chi_O$ is a Borel measurable function.
>   *Hint:* Begin by showing that $\chi_I$ is Borel measurable for each open interval $I$.

The book has defined the Borel measurable functions as the set of fucntions which is closed under pointwise limits and contains the continious functions. I know that if I am able to do what they ask in the hint, then I am finished because ever open set is a countable union of open intervals, so I am just make a sequence of functions for each interval.

However, I am not sure how to prove what they ask in the hint. What I think I need to prove is that for any interval (a,b), there is a sequence of continous function which converges pointwise to 1 on (a,b) and 0 everywhere, and since the borel set of functions are closed under pointwise limits I will be done. However, which sequence of functions should I use?

Comment: Try something like this: For sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb N$ let $f_{(a,b)}^n$ be the function that is $0$ outside $(a,b)$, linear from $a$ to $a+ \frac 1 n$ with $f(a+ \frac 1 n) = 1$, constant from $a+ \frac 1 n$ to $b - \frac 1 n$ and linear from $b - \frac 1 n$ to $b$. To make clear what this means, you might want to sketch the graph of this function.

Comment: @Einer Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome (:

Comment: Next time, write down your question instead of posting an image. Makes it easier to search through questions...

Comment: To  finish I thing to use the fact that: any  open set is a countable union **disjoint** of open intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify that to showing that there is a sequence converging pointwise to $\chi_{(0,1)}$:

$$\begin{align*}
f_n(t) & = \begin{cases}0 & t \notin (0,1) \\
1 & t \in (\frac1n, 1-\frac1n) \\
nt & t\in (0,\frac1n) \\
n(1-t) & t \in (1-\frac1n, 1)\end{cases} \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t) & =  \chi_{(0,1)}(t) & \forall t\in \mathbb R
\end{align*}$$
Suits your needs

Then apply affine transformations ($T: t\mapsto \frac{t-a}{b-a}$) wich are continuous to get to sequences $g_n = f_n \circ T$ for $\chi_{(a,b)}$ for arbitrary $a,b\in\mathbb R$.
Finally you can proceed as you already figured out.

Answer (score 1):

There is $N\in \Bbb N^*$ such that  for all $n\geq N$, $a<a+\frac{1}{n}<b-\frac{1}{n}<b$, and put $f_n(x)= nx-na$ if $x\in (a,a+\frac{1}{n})$, and $f_n(x)=1$ if $x\in (a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n})$, and $f_n(x)=nb-xn$ if $x\in (b-\frac{1}{n},b)$  , and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\notin (a,b)$.

Comment: The formulas given for $f_n$ are incorrect. cf. $f_n(b-\frac 1n) = -1 \ne 1$